# Conditional Probability and Expected Value

Tags: probability

The problem I'm working on is the following

suppose $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and that the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$ is uniform on $(0,y)$ find E[X]

I've gotten that $f(X|Y=y) = \frac{1}{y}$ for $0<x<y$ and I know I can find the answer if I can get $f(x)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you calculate $\mathbb E [X \vert Y =y]$? Then you can use the law of iterated expectations to find $\mathbb E [X]$.

Comment: I think so, is $E[X|Y = y]$ just $\frac{y}{2}$? so the law of iterated expectations tells me that E[X] = E[$\frac{y}{2}$] I feel like I'm close, but that I'm not all the way there

Comment: @JonHales You're pretty much there: now just do $E(Y/2) = E(Y)/2=?$

Comment: Yes, that’s about correct. To be pedantic, $\mathbb E [X] = \mathbb E [Y/2]$, since we want to distinguish between the random variables $X$ and $Y$ and their realisations $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Tower Property, otherwise known as the Law of Iterated Expectation (or Law of Total Expectation, LoTE).

$$\mathsf E(X) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))$$

Now $X\mid Y \sim \mathcal U(0;Y)$ tells you what is $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$.    Just as $Y\sim \mathcal U(0;1)$ tells you what is $\mathsf E(Y)$ .   Everything else is just substitution and applying the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.

---

Or by integration if you must:  $$\mathsf E(X) ~{= \iint_{\Bbb R^2} x f_Y(y)f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\ = \int_0^1\int_0^y \dfrac xy~ \mathrm d x~\mathrm d y}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes perfect sense.